# sockets work on emulator but not on device Android

Tags: android, emulation

I have a strange issue, for a couple days now I thought my issue was with my code, however I got lazy and didn't hook my phone up to the computer to test it, which means it used the emulator to test and HOLY CRAP the sockets connected no problem on the emulator but always a socket timeout on the device. I have the internet permission set in the manifest and am able to ping the server I want to connect to with terminal emulator from my phone...any ideas?

Comment: What is the code you are running, can you post that. Without that there is no way for us to figure out the issue. The most common problem when anyone says the emulator works but the phone doesn't for network is they are trying to connect from an outside machine to a phone (which doesn't work in that direction usually without some special setup).

Comment: Another issue could be that you are running the socket thing within your ui thread...which is not allowed on devices... So please share more info indeed.